# Email Search Using database in postfix, dovcot and imap

Tags: email, search, imap, postfix-mta, dovecot

I have installed rainloop for my office website, though it is very user friendly and i'm using a email server for my domain emails.

I am using Postfix and dovecot in email server. IMAP and SMTP for incoming and outgoing respectively.

Less than 1 000 emails in account is very easy to search, but when it comes to more than 100 000 emails, the search in email subject or from or to is very very slow, and it is taking more than 5 minutes to get the result.

I want to make the email search is fast when it comes to large mailbox case. I'm thinking to make a database based search at least for my email id.

Can anybody help me to get the hooks for email delete, read and unread options in dovecot or postfix? Though I could not able to get any exact clue to retrieve the above.

Comment: Aside: 'lakh' is not well-known term outside of Indian English.  Suggest standard 'hundred thousand'.